# Embedding XNA in WPF: how to update gametime?

Tags: wpf, xna, embedding

I'm trying to embedd an XNA game into my WPF application.
I'm following the code shown here: http://remember.waralan.fr/?p=497 (not in english)

My problem is, gameTime is never updated, and is always 0.
How can I increase as it would be in a normal XNA game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any way to update gameTime by itself, so I updated it manually using C# `stopwatch`.

Thanks to Shawn Hargreaves for his article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/06/when-winforms-met-game-loop.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything in front of me but it's not enough to just instantiate the Game.

I believe you have to actually [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.run.aspx) the game to get the game loop to start.